# Unable to return plain text description with HTTP response code 500 in WCF REST web service

Tags: json, rest, wcf, text, response

## In short

In a WCF REST web service, I throw an exception:

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Test\r\nfailed", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

The browser returns:

```
"Test\r\nfailed"
```

I want it to return:

```
Test
failed
```

## Detailed description

1. I create a new application from **WCF service application** template in **Microsoft Visual Studio Community** 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.5.0 Preview 1.0.
2. I add a new method to **IService1.cs**:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "Test",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Test();
```

3. I add it's implementation to **Service1.cs**:

```
public string Test()
{
    throw new System.ServiceModel.Web.WebFaultException<string>(
        "Test\r\nfailed",
        System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

4. I change the service type from SOAP to REST in **Web.config**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="rest" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="rest">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
...
  </behaviors>
...
</system.serviceModel>
```

5. I start the application in debug mode.

A web browser opens at address **http://localhost:58023**.

6. I change the address to **http://localhost:58023/Service1.svc/Test**.

The browser shows:

```
"Test\r\nfailed"
```

The full server reply is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?V2h5IHRoZSBoZWxsIGFyZSB5b3UgdHJ5aW5nIHRvIGRlY29kZSB0aGlzPw?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2022 15:53:19 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 16

"Test\r\nfailed"
```

If I do the following just before throwing the exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

it only changes the content type in HTTP headers, the body remains JSON-encoded:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
...
"Test\r\nfailed"
```

If I do the following:

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "Bla-bla-bla";
```

it only changes HTTP response description:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Bla-bla-bla
...
"Test\r\nfailed"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the effect you want, you must use an additional back-slash.

```
"Test \\nfailed"
```

Feel free to contact me if have issue.

Comment: Really? Are you f...g serious? Feel free not to reply anymore.